# Converting THREE.js object rotation to Canvas rotation

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, html5-canvas

Hi stackoverflow geniuses. I'm converting three js mesh positions to html5 canvas positions. I'm able to convert vector3 position to canvas position. My problem is converting mesh rotation to canvas rotation.

[image]

What I did is:

```
ctx.rotate(rotation._y);
ctx.rect( 0, 0, width,height);
```

But It does not work. What's the proper way to do it?

thanks

**EDIT:**

```
I think the rotation for mesh object starts at center point so what I did is to tranlate first to the center point then do a rotate which works.


this.context.translate( cx, cy );
this.context.rotate(item.rotation._y);
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? Three.js provides a 3D rotation. Canvas only has a 2D rotation. So in the case above what do you want happen? There is no perfect mapping from 3D rotations to 2D rotations.

Comment: Is there any reference for demonstration of this kind of conversion ?

Comment: Do you want to add something like a [compass](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/adding-compass-to-the-scene/8727/2?u=prisoner849)?

Comment: @prisoner849, I'm building a 3d to 2d view. floorplan from 3d to 2d view. I think the rotation of three js is from center point. So what I did is to first translate point to center then rotate which I got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the THREE.CSSRenderer if you want to render Dom stuff using the 3d scene graph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate it. But I got it working by translating from the center point first then do a rotate.